# Customized html report name in JUnitReport task

Tags: maven, xslt, ant, junit, maven-antrun-plugin

I am using JunitReport task for generating junit report in HTML format using maven.

I have added the below items in pom.xml to generate the test report in HTML

```
<plugin>
            <!-- Extended Maven antrun plugin -->
            <!-- https://maven-antrun-extended-plugin.dev.java.net/ -->
            <groupId>org.jvnet.maven-antrun-extended-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-extended-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-reports</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <junitreport todir="target/surefire-reports">
                                <fileset dir="target/surefire-reports">
                                    <include name="**/*.xml" />
                                </fileset>
                                <report format="noframes" todir="target/surefire-reports" />
                            </junitreport>
                        </tasks>      
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant-junit</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant-trax</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

The html report name is always displayed as **junit-noframes.html**. Since i generate more html reports, every html report is getting generated with same name as **junit-noframes.html**. I want to give custom html report name.

How to change the html report name ? I dont find any options for this.

Comment: any solution for this ?

Comment: It is usually not very helpful to add a comment on your own question, unless there are already listeners (previous commenters or posters): no-one will see it. Instead, consider updating our question, because the usual cause of nobody answering is that either it is too complex to fit a Q&A site, or it is not clear what you are asking. That said, I have meanwhile answered your question ;).

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation says](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html):

> The noframes format does not use redirecting and generates one file called junit-noframes.html.

And doesn't offer a way around that. However, you can use parameters just like with ANT, so the following would work:

```
<report format="noframes" todir="${report.location}" />
```

There are [several ways of setting the parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976063/how-to-pass-parameter-to-ant-scripts), either from the commandline, an environment variable, or a `build.properties` file.

It seems to me that this element does not allow you to change the output filename of the XSLT transformation, however, you could force the output filename if you can write a custom XSLT stylesheet and use an extension function, or if you can configure ANT to use an XSLT 2.0 processor and use `xsl:result-document`. This seems a lot of trouble to fix this, though.

If it suffices in your situation to place them in different directories, then that is the easy way out.

---

Another solution [as proposed by Suntaragali Qa](http://softwaretestersforum.blogspot.nl/2013/10/generate-dynamic-soapui-html-reports.html), you can solve it by moving the file to a new name with a timestamp.

Add this:

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="timestamp" pattern="yyyyMMddHHmmss" />
</tstamp>
```

And change this:

```
<junitreport todir="target/surefire-reports">
    <fileset dir="target/surefire-reports">
        <include name="**/*.xml" />
    </fileset>
    <report 
        format="noframes" 
        todir="target/surefire-reports/html"
        styledir="target/surefire-reports" />
</junitreport>

<move 
    file="target/surefire-reports/html/junit-noframes.html" 
    tofile="target/surefire-reports/html/junit-report-${timestamp}.html" />
```

I think this second solution is much easier to implement and uses standard ANT syntax. See the link for more info on how to do this.